# Spring mapping problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting the following error:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with
>   URI [/my-app] in DispatcherServlet
>   with name 'web'

My web.xml looks like:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And my web-servlet.xml looks like:

```
<bean name="myController" class="com.app.web.MyController" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
         value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Any help / explanation would be great.  Also, what should the view parameter be to `new ModelAndView(?)` in the controller?

My goal is to be able to hit `http://localhost:8080/my-app` and be routed to MyController which would then load a given jsp.

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration looks fine to me. In your `MyController`, make sure you have a request mapping for `my-app`, like this:-

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
   @RequestMapping(value="/my-app", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String mainPage() {
      return "index";
   }
}
```

When you call `http://localhost:8080/my-app`, the server will return the `index.jsp` from `/WEB-INF/jsp/` folder.

Comment: Yup. Alternatively you can use the BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping, but that's rather old school now :-) However if you do define a BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping instance, you'll also have to explicitly request DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter as they won't be implicitly created.

Comment: also, what is the significance of the bean name (where the controller class is specified)?  How does spring know to invoke that controller (since "myController" was never explicitly called)?

Comment: @joe: Take a look at section 13.4.2 at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like DispatcherServlet is trying to process the request for /my-app, which suggests to me that your web.xml servlet-mapping is directing requests for that space to DispatcherServlet.

You might have something like this?

```
<servlet-mapping>   <servlet>dispatcher</servlet>   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
```

Try calling your controllers with a different extension (.do for example) and update the servlet-mapping to suit

```
 <servlet-mapping>   <servlet>dispatcher</servlet>   <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
```

or change /* to /

Hope that helps.